# Change Search result view of uib-typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

What I am trying to do is similar to this but I want in group that all cities of a state should come under that state heading. I have to use Uib-typeahead only.
Refer link below.

https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv

The sample json is like

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Mumbai",
    "state": "Maharashtra"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Delhi",
    "state": "Delhi"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Bengaluru",
    "state": "Karnataka"
},
{
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Pune",
    "state": "Maharashtra"
},
{
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Nagpur",
    "state": "Maharashtra"
}
 ]
```

The output should be like

State should be in Bold

```
 **Maharashtra**         **Delhi**          **Karnataka**
 Pune                      Delhi              Bengaluru
 Mumbai
 Nagpur
```

Comment: Use underscore js maybe ?

Comment: [`ui-select`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) lets you do this, check out [this group-by demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-group-by.html) (you can later apply an included bootstrap theme/style to hide the fact it's a different library)